# What order of infinity is the set of vectors whose components sum to $0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, cardinals, infinity

I was wondering this question today, but I don't really have the machinery to answer it, and I'm not sure how to search for such an answer.  Here's the set up of the problem:

What is the order of infinity of the set of vectors whose components sum to $0$.  Put differently, take a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  If $A= \{x | \mathbf{1} \cdot x =0 \} $  then what is the $size(A)$? And how does it compare to the order of infinity of the set of $x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Is $x$ dense in $x'$? If there was a uniform distribution across all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, what would be the probability of selecting such an $x$?  Intuitively, this last question seems to be related to the cardinality of $x$ but still somewhat different.

Comment: If you are talking about size as in *cardinality*, then it will be the same cardinality as the continuum.  If you are talking about size as in *dimension*, it will be of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: what is $x$ and $x'$? how are points dense in each other?

Comment: In terms of density, no, it is certainly not dense (*assuming usual topology*).  Consider a ball of radius $1$ around $[2,2,2,2,\dots,2]$.  Every vector within that ball has only strictly positive entries and so clearly does not belong to $A$.  In terms of probability, you cannot have a uniform probability distribution over an unbounded infinite set so the question makes no sense.  I expect any sensible probability distribution or limits of distributions that you try to use though to approximate what you want will end up with it being probability zero.

Comment: Ah ok thank you @JMoravitz, my tired brain couldn't figure out the density thing.  Also I guess improper priors have spoiled me, but I see your point, question would probably still have the same answer with a uniform distribution over a bounded set say in $[0,1]$.  I knew that the answer would probably be $0$, I just wasn't sure if it was closer tied to cardinality or dimensionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality is the same as $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, which is the size of the continuum for $n \gt 1$.  You can choose the first $n-1$ coordinates at will, then have to choose the last one to make the sum zero.  It forms an $n-1$ dimensional surface in $R^n$ with $0 \ n-$ dimensional volume.  From the measure point of view the chance of getting one of these vectors is zero just like the chance of picking a specific real.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ because both can be considered the cross product of $\mathbb{R}$ and itself?  Or am I now confusing cardinality properties of unions and cross products? Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You just need that $\Bbb R^2$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$, then you can extend that to any finite power.  We have questions on that here.  You can biject $\Bbb R$ with $(0,1)$, then match up $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ with $(0,1)$ by interleaving the decimal expansions.